# Browser reading HTML from standard input

Tags: html, linux, browser, input, standards

Does anyone know a Linux browser (it can be console-based) that can read an HTML page from its standard input? For example, I want to do this:

```
generate_html | browser
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
echo hello! | lynx -stdin
```

Comment: add `-dump` to send result to stdout

Comment: `echo "<h1>Hello</h1>" | bcat` from http://superuser.com/questions/526327/rendering-html-from-a-pipe